# implement eq selector with cell().data()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please check the example bellow. On bottom in javascript section you will see a datatables framework function cell().data() used to change first < td > text but there i didn't selected any of specific < td > so by default this changing the text of first < td >. But my goal is i want to select my "< td >" with "$row.find('td:eq(2)'))" jquery function. But keep in mind i must have to use the cell().data() function to change text. In short actually i wanted to control cell.().data() with jquery eq selector. How can i do it?

Note: I am using [datatables framework](https://datatables.net/reference/api/cell().data()) on this example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Demo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2011/07/25</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2009/01/12</td>
                <td>$86,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2012/03/29</td>
                <td>$433,060</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable();

    //$row.find('td:eq(2)'));

    var table = $('#example').DataTable();
    table.cell().data("fooo");


});


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through all the cells and filter the column index.
So, once you get the right cell, you can set the property data as you like.

```
table.cells( function ( idx, data, node ) {
    if(idx.column == 2) {
      table.cell(idx).data("fooo");
    }
});
```

See following snippet please:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable();
    var test = table.cells( function ( idx, data, node ) {
        if(idx.column == 2) {
          table.cell(idx).data("fooo");
        }
    } );
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2011/04/25</td>
            <td>$320,800</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Garrett Winters</td>
            <td>Accountant</td>
            <td>Tokyo</td>
            <td>63</td>
            <td>2011/07/25</td>
            <td>$170,750</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Ashton Cox</td>
            <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>66</td>
            <td>2009/01/12</td>
            <td>$86,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
            <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>22</td>
            <td>2012/03/29</td>
            <td>$433,060</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I hope it helps you, bye.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change only the first cell, you can pass the jQuery node to the [`table.cell()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/cell()) method, so this will work and if I understand correctly, will do what you're after:

`table.cell($('#example td:eq(2)')).data("fred")`

Comment: The `cell()` method select just one cell, you cannot use this method to change many cell at the same time. Please see the [documentation here](https://datatables.net/reference/api/cell())

Comment: @Alessandro - I'm not sure why you voted my suggestion down - the OP stated "In short actually i wanted to control cell.().data() with jquery eq selector. How can i do it?" - that's exactly what I covered!